# Localizing templates with backbone, underscore on mobile

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I want to localize templates in my Phonegap/Backbone mobile App. I want to somehow override underscore render function in a way that would always append extra attribute with languages. Let me show that on example:

lets say I required (require.js) the HomeView template wich looks like:

```
<div>
   <p><%= language.get('someText') %></p>
</div>
```

In my HomeView.js I have:

```
var template = _.template(HomeTemplate);
this.$el.html( template({language: LanguageModel}));
```

This works, but I don't want to always append this language attribute to underscore template. Could I somehow overwrite that render function so It would always include language Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put any JavaScript expression you like inside `<%= ... %>`. In particular, you can access globals. So, if you have a global application namespace:

```
// I'll call it `app` for lack of a better placeholder.
window.app = { ... };
```

Then you can put `language` in there:

```
app.language = your_language_model;
```

and access it in any template without supplying anything extra to the `_.template` call or the compiled template function:

```
var t = _.template('<%= app.language.get('pancakes') %>');
var h = t();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jkmG7/1/

Comment: I just get the idea of accessing global variable. You saved me from my missery. Big thanks.